# XML Serializing and Deserializing List Data in Android App

Tags: c#, android, xml, serialization, xamarin

So I am trying to deserialize and serialize a List.

The issue: The list(list1) is not saving to the file called "ListData" which should be created if not already there, into the documents folder in the android internal storage.

I think the file may not be creating properly or something, or the filepath is incorrect. Below is how it should be functioning but that isn't working as explained with the issue above.

I want to save the filename as something like "ListData".
Also, needs to be saved into the Internal Storage somewhere such as the Data folder of the app or Documents in internal storage.

The following is what i have for the code, but I can't seem to find any help elsewhere to fix my issue. It doesn't work, any ideas for a solution to what I want it to do?

Code:

```
public abstract class DataHandler
{
    public static void SaveLists()
    {
        string filePath = Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDocuments;
        string fileName = "ListData";

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Item>));
        Stream writer = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);

        serializer.Serialize(writer, _LISTFROMANOTHERCLASS_);

        writer.Close();
    }

    public static void LoadLists()
    {
        string filePath = Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDocuments;
        string fileName = "ListData";

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Item>));
        Stream reader = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
        List<Item> list1 = new List<Item>();

        list1 = (List<Item>) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        _LISTFROMANOTHERCLASS_ = list1;

        reader.Close();

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: Please define "doesn't work".  What does it do or not do?  Do you get exceptions or errors?  Also, consider using Newtonsoft.JSON for serialization.  It works well with Xamarin and is very well documented.

Comment: The issue: The list(list1) is not saving to the file called "ListData" which should be created if not already there, into the documents folder in the android internal storage.

Comment: @Jason I've added it now, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I have written a class to do these but with JSON serlization check is it helps it uses MVVM Cross, It has code written to encrypt and decrypt data you can avoid these parts

```
 public class PersistantStorageHelper<T>
    {
        IMvxFileStoreAsync _mvxFileStoreAsync;
        IMvxFileStore _mvxFileStore;
        EDEngine bcEngine = new EDEngine(new AesEngine(), Encoding.UTF8);
        string currentkey_temp_dev = "AthulHarikumar00";//This static key is not being used it is a just a place holder

        public PersistantStorageHelper() {
            this._mvxFileStore = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxFileStore>();
            this._mvxFileStoreAsync = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxFileStoreAsync>();
            bcEngine.SetPadding(new Pkcs7Padding());
            currentkey_temp_dev = Constants.PassPhrase.Substring(4, 12)+"Road";
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public async Task<T> GetPersistantObject(T obj)
        {
            var fileName = (typeof(T).ToString().Replace(".", "_"));
           var x= await GetPersistantObject(obj, fileName);
            return x;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// If object exists returns the object else saves a plain object and returns it
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj">empty placeholder object</param>
        /// <returns>Filesystem object</returns>
        public async Task<T> GetPersistantObject( T obj,string fileName) {

            List<string> files = new List<string>(_mvxFileStore.GetFilesIn(_mvxFileStore.NativePath("")));
            fileName = _mvxFileStore.NativePath(fileName);

            if (!files.Contains(fileName))
            {
                var objJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

                objJson= bcEngine.Encrypt(objJson, currentkey_temp_dev);
                await _mvxFileStoreAsync.WriteFileAsync(fileName,objJson);
            }
            else {
                try
                {

                    var temp = await _mvxFileStoreAsync.TryReadTextFileAsync(fileName);
                    var str = bcEngine.Decrypt(temp.Result, currentkey_temp_dev);
                    obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(str);
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    var objJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

                    objJson = bcEngine.Encrypt(objJson, currentkey_temp_dev);
                    await _mvxFileStoreAsync.WriteFileAsync(fileName, objJson);
                }
            }

            return obj;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public async Task<T> SetPersistantObject(T obj)
        {
            var fileName = _mvxFileStore.NativePath(typeof(T).ToString().Replace(".", "_"));
            var temp = await SetPersistantObject(obj, fileName);
            return temp;

        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Saves object to persistant storage with encryption
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj">object to be stored</param>
        /// <returns>Saved object</returns>
        public async Task<T> SetPersistantObject(T obj,string fileName)
        {

            List<string> files = new List<string>(_mvxFileStore.GetFilesIn(_mvxFileStore.NativePath("")));
             fileName = _mvxFileStore.NativePath(fileName);


                var objJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
            objJson = bcEngine.Encrypt(objJson, currentkey_temp_dev);
            await _mvxFileStoreAsync.WriteFileAsync(fileName, objJson);



            return obj;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

java.util.List is not serializable, but java.util.ArrayList is. So just change List to ArrayList on both sites (left before variablename and right for constructor). Also check if your Item implements Serializable

Comment: I don't think that helps answer the question in full, but thank you anyways.